# construct GUI with event dispatch thread and make assignment

Tags: multithreading, events, variable-assignment, event-dispatch-thread, dispatch

I'd like to do the following without making the variable gui `final`:

```java
public class MainClass
{

        GUIClass gui;
        Runnable r = new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                // this won't work!
                gui = new GUIClass();
            }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
        Controller c = new Controller(gui);     

}
```

How can I achieve that? I want to construct the gui via the EDT. At the same time I want to assign that new instance to the variable gui. But this won't work without making gui `final`. I don't want to use `final` because it's not possible in my context. Anyone any idea how this could be solved? The code above is of course executed within the main method. But for some reasons I couldn't post it here as an error occured.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all those who should be interested in this issue someday, here's the solution:
I made a mistake. Actually you should differentiate between constructing the GUI-Object and making it visible. So here is the way to do that:

```java
public class MainClass
{

        final GUIClass gui = new GUIClass();
        Runnable r = new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {           
                gui.pack();
                gui.setVisible(true);
            }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
        Controller c = new Controller(gui);     

}
```